# SQL transform row to column, complex type

Tags: sql, sqlite, pivot

I need to transform this table to this table... It's a kind of pivoting the table.

My Table

```
year    state   Bar         Rest        disco       grocery     pharmacy
1945    CAL     220530236   9282364     0           3202436     0
1950    CAL     245988038   12181674    0           0       0
1955    CAL     268003540   10666664    0           180346      0
1945    NYC     21063922    353380      0           230132      0
1950    NYC     24450958    359908      4012        224012      2006
1955    NYC     27939064    434320      2006        893216      1003
```

What I need

```
State   Type        1945        1950        1955        
CAL     Bar         220530236   245988038   268003540           
CAL     Rest        9282364     12181674    10666664                    
CAL     disco       0           0           0           
CAL     grocery     3202436     0           180346              
CAL     pharmacy    0           0           0
NYC     Bar         21063922    24450958    27939064                
NYC     Rest        353380      359908      434320
NYC     disco       0           4012        2006
NYC     grocery     230132      224012      893216
NYC     pharmacy    0           2006        1003
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an unpivot/pivot operation.  In SQLite, you can use `union all` and conditional aggregation:

```
select state, type,
       max(case when year = 1945 then val end) as val_1945,
       max(case when year = 1950 then val end) as val_1950,
       max(case when year = 1955 then val end) as val_1955
from (select year, state, 'bar' as type, bar as val
      from t
      union all
      select year, state, 'rest' as type, rest as val
      from t
      union all
      select year, state, 'disco' as type, disco as val
      from t
      union all
      select year, state, 'grocery' as type, grocery as val
      from t
      union all
      select year, state, 'pharmacy' as type, pharmacy as val
      from t
     ) t
group by state, type
order by state, type;
```